# How to find people near me using google maps in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to store user longitude and latitude in mysql and want to push a notification when user is in 2Km Range In Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use googleFirebase for this feature.

your concept like ola, uber  right.

Comment: Thanks. can you elaborate little more :)